# Power BI: Running total appears fine in table, but not showing in line chart

Tags: powerbi

[image: Table and resulting visualisation]

As you can see, running totals appear fine. e.g.
For created tickets, values are as follows:

| Created Date | Count | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2021 | 2 | 2 |
| 02/11/2021 | 3 | 5 |
| 03/11/2021 | 4 | 9 |
| 04/11/2021 | 3 | 12 |
| 05/11/2021 | 3 | 15 |

You can also see that the graph should be using the measure to generate the lines but for some reason it's not showing the running total; just the daily count.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The graph that you added shows 2 different tables.  You need to use the same table for both line graphs.  First line should be the count column while the second should be the running count.

Comment: @sydadder Why should that matter? Only shows that the issue can be reproduced for two different tables.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the formula for the measure(s).

Comment: @teylyn the second table doesnt have the right values.. it is clear on the image

Comment: @sydadder The first table plots the value 0,2,3,4,3,3,0 and its accumulated totals are 2,5,9,12,15, but these are not plotted. The second table plots the values 0,0,3,2,0,2,0 and its accumulated values are 3,5,7, but these are not plotted. Two tables, same problem.

Comment: Thank you teylyn and sydadder. I resolved this by appending the two datasets into one table. I thought I could have the two datasets connected by a date table to produce my required result but as you said, sydadder, this is no good.
I will update the question with same info.
Thank you both again for your responses.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add RESOLVED or SOLVED to the question title, or to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution and want to share it with others, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by appending the two datasets into one table. I thought I could have the two datasets connected by a date table to produce my required result but as pointed out by sydadder, this is no good.

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr2EG.png)